# Discover prisma table's primary key at runtime?

Tags: prisma

In prisma.io how do I find the name of a table's primary key?  It is defined in file schema.prisma, but how to I identify the primary key of any arbitrary table at runtime, given the table's name?

So far I can find no reference to this in the documentation for Prisma Client.  After instantiating PrismaClient I can find the list of tables and their column names (prisma._baseDmmf.datamodel.models), but no hint of which column(s) is the primary key.

Comment: Why do you need to find a primary key on runtime ?

Comment: For a basic CRUD admin page for my database.  In other words not for a particularly good reason, re-inventing the wheel, but still I'd like to know.

Comment: Ok, the only thing I can think of is a [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Do you mean use a raw query to query the underlying database schema?  I'm currently trying to construct the query `const result = await prisma[TABLE_NAME].findUnique({where: { PRIMARY_KEY: 123 }})` where TABLE_NAME and PRIMARY_KEY are variable.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer.  I imported Prisma (in addition to PrismaClient) which provides access to `Prisma.dmmf.datamodel.models` which is an array of table models.  Each table model includes an array of field definitions, each of which has the boolean property `isId`, which is true if that field is the row id.

For example:

`Prisma.dmmf.datamodel.models[1].fields[0].isId`

The names of each table and each field are string properties:

`Prisma.dmmf.datamodel.models[1].name == 'Assets'`

`Prisma.dmmf.datamodel.models[1].fields[0].name == 'AssetId'`

Hope this helps someone.